# Show-hide based on two sets of selectors--how to make them work together?

Tags: jquery, filter, css-selectors, show-hide

This calendar has filters for type of event (using checkboxes) and region (links with hot images). I can get either set of filters to work independently but how in the heck do I get them to work together? Would it be better to use radio buttons instead of images or is there some way to "remember" what image was last selected?

This jQuery code worked to select the regions. I used something similar to select the event types. I just can't get them bundled into one jQuery that works together to show selected event types in the selected region!

**jQuery for selecting one region**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // showall the events
    $("#calendar p").show();

    $("td.filters a").click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var regionid = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#calendar p").hide(); //hide all

    $("." + regionid).show(); //show only selected region
    });
;
```

The user may choose several checkboxes but only one region (red, blue, all) at a time, so we're looking at thisregion AND (thistype OR thattype). If the user changes the region, only the selected event types should show. If the user changes the selected event types, the previously selected region should still show. The jQuery below doesn't work.

With this part of the jQuery:

```
selector += "#" + regionid + "." + "check_" + $(this).attr("id") + ", "; 
// builds a selector like "red.type1, red.type2, blue.type3, "
```

I am trying to build a selector that ends up with (red AND type1) for the first paragraph, (red AND type2) for the second, and (blue AND type3) for the third. I am not sure how to do that!

**HTML**

```
<div class="filters">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_events" id="typeAny" /> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_events" id="type1" /> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_events" id="type2" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_events" id="type3" />
    <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="all">All</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="red">Red</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="blue">Blue</a></li>
    </ul>
</div> 
<table id="calendar">
    <tr>   
        <td><p class="all red typeAny type1">Type 1 event in red region</p></td>
        <td><<p class="all red typeAny type2">Type 2 event in red region</p></td>
        <td><<p class="all blue typeAny type3">Type 3 event in blue region</p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.all a, #all a{display:block; background:gray;color:black; }
.red a, #red a{display:block; background:red;color:black; }
.blue a, #blue a{display:block; background:blue;color:black; }
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $checkboxes = $("input[id^='check_']");
    $("#calendar p").show();
    $("td.filters a").click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var regionid = $(this).attr("id");
        var selector = "";
        $checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function(){ // checked         
            selector += "#" + regionid + "." + "check_" + $(this).attr("id") + ", "; 
            // builds a selector like "red.type1, red.type2, blue.type3, "     
        });    
        selector = selector.substring(0, selector.length - 2); // remove trailing ', '    
        $("#calendar p").hide() // hide all events       
            .filter(selector).show(); // reduce set to matched and show  
    }).change(); 
});
```

Comment: Reasons why I woted down that question posted in answer (comments has a low characters limit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not code, but some kind of nonsense:

- eventSelected - where it come from? Do you meant `selector = selector.substring(0, selector.length - 2);`?
- $("td.filters a") - I don't see any tables or tr's or td's in your code
- Empty `href` attribure for links? Are you kidding me? Use 'javascript:void(0)' or 'javascript:;' or '#'!
- `$(".calendar p").show();` - what that means? I don't see any paragraphs in `div.calendar`.
- `selector += "#" + regionid + "." + "check_" + $(this).attr("id") + ", ";` i don't see any possibility when this selector may really select something. Maybe it's better to use `show()` function for each event in `each` cycle instead of constructing some monster selector?

There is no possibility to help you with the given code. Try to rewrite it properly and I'll try to help. Currently its impossible.

Comment: I corrected the errors made when I tried to abstract the situation for stack overflow. My bad.

Comment: @coolEsh, how would you write a show() function for each event in each cycle and what is a cycle? Sorry I know so little about jQuery.

Comment: @coolEsh, thanks for pointing out the inconsistencies! Now maybe we can get somewhere.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bvna3/9/ - here is the solution. btw why my comment deserve a vote down?

Comment: @coolEsh, someone else voted your answer down and voted my question back up to zero. I'll look at your answer later today.

Comment: @coolEsh, well, I couldn't wait! Looks good. I'm curious about a couple things. Why doesn't the table show onload? It looks like it should. If you change the type, you still have to click on a color (region) to see the particular events. Any way to tweak the code to get that to happen without having to choose both selectors every time? In other words, any way to get the value that picked before for region if you change event type? I guess that means storing the value in a variable.

Comment: "Why doesn't the table show onload?" - because I thought that events need to be shown only after selection of region. If I understand you correctly than that code will work as you need: http://jsfiddle.net/CoolEsh/bvna3/13/